# Determinant of an $n\times n$ Toeplitz matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, toeplitz-matrices

Let $A = (a_{ij}) \in R^{n\times n}$. Find the determinant if:

$$a_{ij}= |i-j|$$

So we have the symmetric matrix
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & \dots & n-1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & \dots & n-2 \\
2 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & \dots & n-3 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
n-1 & n-2 & n-3 & \dots & \dots & \dots & 0
\end{bmatrix}

But i can't find a way to diagonalize the matrix nor find the determinant by Laplace expansion.

Any ideas ??

Comment: looks like $(-1)^n n 2^{n-1}$ could be the answer... See here: http://oeis.org/A085750

Comment: Such matrices are called [Toeplitz matrices](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix), and there exist "fast" algorithms for computing their determinants.

Comment: But I've to use "regular methods" (row or columns operations, Laplace expansion..) to argument an answer, in fact i had to calculate the determinants of $a_{ij}$ = $max(i,j)$ and $a_{ij}$ = $min(i,j)$ and I used those methods, do you think it's possible to calculate that matrix in a similar way ??

Comment: @Fabian The sign’s wrong in your proposed solution. It’ll be $(-1)^{n-1}$.

Comment: @amd: I think, it should be $n\mapsto n-1$ in my suggestion.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3736861/339790

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If we do row reduction, i.e. $R_n-R_{n-1}$, $R_{n-1}-R_{n-2}$, up to $R_2-R_1$, and then again do $R_n-R_{n-1}$, $R_{n-1}-R_{n-2}$, up to $R_3-R_2$ and finally $R_2+R_1$, then we get
\begin{align}
&\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & \cdots & n-1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & \cdots & n-2 \\
2 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & \cdots & n-3 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
n-1 & n-2 & n-3 & \cdots & \cdots & \dots & 0
\end{vmatrix}\\ \ \\
=&\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & \cdots & n-1 \\
1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & \cdots & -1 \\
1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & \cdots & -1 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
1&1&1&\cdots&\cdots&-1&-1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & \cdots & 1 & -1
\end{vmatrix}\\ \ \\
=&\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & \cdots & n-1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & \cdots & n-1 \\
0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0&0&0&\cdots&2&0&0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & \cdots & 2 & 0
\end{vmatrix}\\
\end{align}
Now we calculate the determinant and its minors all by the last row:
\begin{align}
=&\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & \cdots & n-1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & \cdots & n-1 \\
0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0&0&0&\cdots&2&0&0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & \cdots & 2 & 0
\end{vmatrix}\\ \ \\
=&-2\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & \cdots & n-1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & \cdots & n-1 \\
0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0&0&0&\cdots&\cdots&2&0 \\
\end{vmatrix}\\ \ \\
&=(-1)^{n-2}2^{n-2}\begin{vmatrix}0&n-1\\1&n-1 \end{vmatrix}\\ \ \\
&=(-1)^{n-1}2^{n-2}(n-1).
\end{align}

Comment: Appreciate it, in fact I did the first row reduction but I didn't see a clear path from there.
Thanks to everyone for the help

Comment: Nice answer. +1. I was wondering whether this can be done using definition of determinants (as summation over permutations, etc - in this case it will be over all derangements)

Comment: That sounds complicated: all diagonals but one are nonzero, so it's all about the cancelations.

Answer (score 2):

Call your matrix $A$ and let $J$ be the upper triangular nilpotent Jordan block of size $n$ (i.e. the superdiagonal of $J$ contains ones and all other entries are zero). Then $A=U+U^T$, where $U=J+2J^2+\ldots+(n-1)J^{n-1}$. Now, note that $(I-J)U=J+J^2+\ldots+J^{n-1}$ is the strictly upper triangular matrix of ones. Therefore
$$
(I-J)U(I-J^T)=
\pmatrix{
-1&&&&1\\
  &-1&&&1\\
    &&\ddots&&1\\
      &&&-1&1\\
         &&&&0
}
$$
and hence
\begin{align*}
B &:= (I-J)A(I-J^T) = (I-J)(U+U^T)(I-J^T) \\
&= (I-J)U(I-J^T) + ((I-J)U(I-J^T))^T \\
&=
\pmatrix{
-2&&&&1\\
  &-2&&&1\\
    &&\ddots&&1\\
      &&&-2&1\\
         1&1&\cdots&1&0
}.
\end{align*}
Since $\det(I-J)=1$, we get $\det B=\det A$. Now, adding one half of each of the first $n-1$ rows of $B$ to the last row, we get
$$
\det B=
\det\pmatrix{
-2&&&&1\\
&-2&&&1\\
&&\ddots&&1\\
&&&-2&1\\
&&&&\frac{n-1}2
}=\frac{(-2)^{n-1}(n-1)}2.
$$

Comment: Nice approach. +1