# Determinant of a Toeplitz matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, toeplitz-matrices

How can I calculate the determinant of the following Toeplitz matrix?

\begin{bmatrix}
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10\\
2&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9 \\
3&2&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8 \\
4&3&2&1&2&3&4&5&6&7 \\
5&4&3&2&1&2&3&4&5&6 \\
6&5&4&3&2&1&2&3&4&5 \\
7&6&5&4&3&2&1&2&3&4 \\
8&7&6&5&4&3&2&1&2&3 \\
9&8&7&6&5&4&3&2&1&2 \\
10&9&8&7&6&5&4&3&2&1 \\
\end{bmatrix}

Comment: Please provide some context for the problem. Where did you come across this problem? What are your thoughts on it, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: [OEIS sequence A001792](https://oeis.org/A001792) may help.

Comment: I used the [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr) script `for(n=1,10,print1(matdet(matrix(n,n,i,j,abs(i-j)+1))","))` which printed `1,-3,8,-20,48,-112,256,-576,1280,-2816,` and I searched for that in the OEIS.

Comment: A distant relative: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2578797

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We define the following $n \times n$ (symmetric) [Toeplitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix) matrix

$${\rm A}_n := \begin{bmatrix}
          1      & 2      & 3      & \dots  & n-1    & n     \\
          2      & 1      & 2      & \dots  & n-2    & n-1   \\
          3      & 2      & 1      & \dots  & n-3    & n-2   \\
          \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
          n-1    & n-2    & n-3    & \dots  & 1      & 2     \\
          n      & n-1    & n-2    & \dots  & 2      & 1     \\
         \end{bmatrix}$$

Hence,

$${\rm A}_{n+1} = \begin{bmatrix} {\rm A}_n & {\rm c}_n\\ {\rm c}_n^\top & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

where ${\rm c}_n = {\rm A}_n {\rm e}_n + {\Bbb 1}_n$. Computing the determinant,

$$\det \left( {\rm A}_{n+1} \right) = \det \begin{bmatrix} {\rm A}_n & {\rm c}_n\\ {\rm c}_n^\top & 1\end{bmatrix} = \left( 1 - {\rm c}_n^\top {\rm A}_n^{-1} {\rm c}_n \right) \det \left( {\rm A}_n \right)$$

where

$$\begin{aligned} {\rm c}_n^\top {\rm A}_n^{-1} {\rm c}_n &= \left( {\rm A}_n {\rm e}_n + {\Bbb 1}_n \right)^\top {\rm A}_n^{-1} \left( {\rm A}_n {\rm e}_n + {\Bbb 1}_n \right)\\ &= \underbrace{{\rm e}_n^\top {\rm A}_n {\rm e}_n}_{= 1} + \underbrace{{\rm e}_n^\top {\Bbb 1}_n}_{= 1} + \underbrace{{\Bbb 1}_n^\top {\rm e}_n}_{= 1} + \underbrace{{\Bbb 1}_n^\top {\rm A}_n^{-1} {\Bbb 1}_n}_{= \frac{2}{n+1}} = 3 + \frac{2}{n+1}\end{aligned}$$

and, thus,

$$\boxed{ \quad \det \left( {\rm A}_{n+1} \right) = -2 \left( \frac{n+2}{n+1} \right) \det \left( {\rm A}_n \right) \quad }$$

and, since $\det \left( {\rm A}_1 \right) = 1$, after some work, we eventually conclude that

$$\color{blue}{\boxed{ \quad \det \left( {\rm A}_n \right) = (-1)^{n-1} \left( n + 1 \right) 2 ^{n-2} \quad }}$$

which is related to integer sequence [A001792](https://oeis.org/A001792), as [pointed out](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3736861/determinant-of-a-toeplitz-matrix/3737109#comment7683239_3736861) by Somos.

---

#### Addendum

How to show the following?

$${\Bbb 1}_n^\top {\rm A}_n^{-1} {\Bbb 1}_n = \frac{2}{n+1}$$

Note that the $n$-th column of matrix ${\rm A}_n$ is the *reversal* of its first column. Hence,

$${\rm A}_n \left( {\rm e}_1 + {\rm e}_n \right) = (n+1) {\Bbb 1}_n$$

Left-multiplying both sides by ${\Bbb 1}_n^\top {\rm A}_n^{-1}$,

$$\underbrace{{\Bbb 1}_n^\top {\rm A}_n^{-1} {\rm A}_n \left( {\rm e}_1 + {\rm e}_n \right)}_{= {\Bbb 1}_n^\top \left( {\rm e}_1 + {\rm e}_n \right) = 2} = (n+1) {\Bbb 1}_n^\top {\rm A}_n^{-1} {\Bbb 1}_n$$

and, thus,

$${\Bbb 1}_n^\top {\rm A}_n^{-1} {\Bbb 1}_n = \frac{2}{n+1}$$

---

#### SymPy code

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> [ Matrix(n, n, lambda i,j: 1 + abs(i-j)).det() for n in range(1,11) ]
[1, -3, 8, -20, 48, -112, 256, -576, 1280, -2816]
```

Comment: If the matrix were circulant, we would have integer sequence [A052182](https://oeis.org/A052182).

Comment: Dear @Rodrigo de Azevedo, thank you a lot for teaching me this nice trick :) Helped me with another quite similar problem a lot to derive the eigenvalues analytically!

Comment: @Sl0wp0k3 You're welcome! Glad to hear that my answer was useful to you.

Answer (score 3):

some patterns.... there is a bit of cancellation in the fractions, before that the diagonal matrix, term at position $jj$ ( for $j \geq 2$) is
$$ -2 \left( \frac{j+1}{j} \right)  $$
which leads to some telescoping in the determinant of the diagonal matrix, and this is the same (integer) as the original matrix.
The relationship $Q^T D Q = H$ for symmetric $H$ and $\det Q = 1$ is called congruence.

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 0 \\ 
2 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 2 \\ 
0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 2 \\ 
2 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
3 &  \frac{ 4 }{ 3 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 3 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 8 }{ 3 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 4 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
2 & 1 & 2 \\ 
3 & 2 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
3 &  \frac{ 4 }{ 3 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
4 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 5 }{ 4 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 3 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 8 }{ 3 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 4 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 5 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 4 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
2 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
3 & 2 & 1 & 2 \\ 
4 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
3 &  \frac{ 4 }{ 3 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
4 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 5 }{ 4 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
5 & 2 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 6 }{ 5 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 8 }{ 3 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 12 }{ 5 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 4 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 5 }{ 3 }  & 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 4 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 6 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
3 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 2 \\ 
5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
3 &  \frac{ 4 }{ 3 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
4 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 5 }{ 4 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
5 & 2 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 6 }{ 5 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
6 &  \frac{ 7 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 7 }{ 4 }  &  \frac{ 7 }{ 5 }  &  \frac{ 7 }{ 6 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 8 }{ 3 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 12 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 7 }{ 3 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 4 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 5 }{ 3 }  & 2 &  \frac{ 7 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 4 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 7 }{ 4 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 6 }{ 5 }  &  \frac{ 7 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 7 }{ 6 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 
2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
3 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 2 \\ 
6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$ \tiny \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
3 &  \frac{ 4 }{ 3 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
4 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 5 }{ 4 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
5 & 2 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 6 }{ 5 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
6 &  \frac{ 7 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 7 }{ 4 }  &  \frac{ 7 }{ 5 }  &  \frac{ 7 }{ 6 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
7 &  \frac{ 8 }{ 3 }  & 2 &  \frac{ 8 }{ 5 }  &  \frac{ 4 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 8 }{ 7 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 8 }{ 3 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 12 }{ 5 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 7 }{ 3 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 16 }{ 7 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrrr} 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 4 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 5 }{ 3 }  & 2 &  \frac{ 7 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 8 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 4 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 7 }{ 4 }  & 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 6 }{ 5 }  &  \frac{ 7 }{ 5 }  &  \frac{ 8 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 7 }{ 6 }  &  \frac{ 4 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 8 }{ 7 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrrr} 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\ 
2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 
3 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 2 \\ 
7 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

jump to 10  ................................

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
3 &  \frac{ 4 }{ 3 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
4 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 5 }{ 4 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
5 & 2 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 6 }{ 5 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
6 &  \frac{ 7 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 7 }{ 4 }  &  \frac{ 7 }{ 5 }  &  \frac{ 7 }{ 6 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
7 &  \frac{ 8 }{ 3 }  & 2 &  \frac{ 8 }{ 5 }  &  \frac{ 4 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 8 }{ 7 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
8 & 3 &  \frac{ 9 }{ 4 }  &  \frac{ 9 }{ 5 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 9 }{ 7 }  &  \frac{ 9 }{ 8 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
9 &  \frac{ 10 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  & 2 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 10 }{ 7 }  &  \frac{ 5 }{ 4 }  &  \frac{ 10 }{ 9 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
10 &  \frac{ 11 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 11 }{ 4 }  &  \frac{ 11 }{ 5 }  &  \frac{ 11 }{ 6 }  &  \frac{ 11 }{ 7 }  &  \frac{ 11 }{ 8 }  &  \frac{ 11 }{ 9 }  &  \frac{ 11 }{ 10 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 8 }{ 3 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 12 }{ 5 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 7 }{ 3 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 16 }{ 7 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 9 }{ 4 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 20 }{ 9 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 11 }{ 5 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrr} 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 4 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 5 }{ 3 }  & 2 &  \frac{ 7 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 8 }{ 3 }  & 3 &  \frac{ 10 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 11 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 4 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 7 }{ 4 }  & 2 &  \frac{ 9 }{ 4 }  &  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 11 }{ 4 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 6 }{ 5 }  &  \frac{ 7 }{ 5 }  &  \frac{ 8 }{ 5 }  &  \frac{ 9 }{ 5 }  & 2 &  \frac{ 11 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 7 }{ 6 }  &  \frac{ 4 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 5 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 11 }{ 6 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 8 }{ 7 }  &  \frac{ 9 }{ 7 }  &  \frac{ 10 }{ 7 }  &  \frac{ 11 }{ 7 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 9 }{ 8 }  &  \frac{ 5 }{ 4 }  &  \frac{ 11 }{ 8 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 10 }{ 9 }  &  \frac{ 11 }{ 9 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 11 }{ 10 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrr} 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\ 
2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\ 
3 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\ 
4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\ 
5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 
6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
7 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
8 & 7 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
9 & 8 & 7 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 2 \\ 
10 & 9 & 8 & 7 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$