# Determinant of family of Toeplitz matrices. Can we use recursion?

Tags: combinatorics, determinant, recursion, integers, toeplitz-matrices

When investigating [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3736861/determinant-of-toeplitz-matrix) regarding matrix let us call it $M_{10}$ I found a peculiar pattern which I can't prove.

We can define $M_n$ to be the $n\times n$ Toeplitz matrix where the elements of the $k$th off diagonal is $k+1$.

It seems to me that at least for 5 or 6 different values of $n$ that $$\det(M_n) = (n+1)\cdot (-1)^{n+1} \cdot 2^{n-2}$$

Maybe recursion can be fruitful? To consider we know $\det(M_n)$ and to try and calculate $\det(M_{n+1})$.

Comment: I'd try to factorize it as product of matrices (LU maybe?)

Comment: @Exodd You are correct. The L factor seems very sparse. Only two non-zero columns except for a diagonal of ones. And linearly spaced elements in those columns